# Where is a named semaphore stored?

Tags: linux, semaphore

A named semaphore (using `semaphore.h`) is identified by a name in the form `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.

As the name corresponds to pathname in filesystem. Where is this semaphore located?`ipcs` is for System V semaphores.How to locate POSIX semaphores?

Comment: Please do not post identical questions to multiple Stack Exchange sites.  This question [can be found on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/36542516).

Answer (score 10):

From [man 7 sem_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) :

> **Accessing named semaphores via the filesystem**
>
> On Linux, named semaphores are created in a virtual filesystem, normally mounted under
>   **`/dev/shm`**, with names of the form `sem.somename`. (This is the reason
>   that semaphore names are limited to NAME_MAX-4 rather than NAME_MAX
>   characters.)

Comment: This answer is a verbatim copy from `man 7 sem_overview`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html and should be annotated as such.

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/<pid>/maps/` will show you the memory mapping of a process with a specific PID. (Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps)

From the output, POSIX semaphores are shown as files in `/dev/shm/`.